# Wrapping long text in CSS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have text like

```
<div style="float:left; width: 250px"> PellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesquePellentesque  feugiat tempor elit. 
Ut mollis lacinia quam. Sed pharetra, augue aliquam   ornare vestibulum, metus massalaoreet tellus, eget iaculis lacus ipsum et diam. </div>
```

I do not want horizontal scrolling. Is it possible to wrap the text (auto-line break). I know there are some IE specific properties.

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE: I can use jQuery, Javascript, PHP to do this also. but how? I mean the letters (font) are not fixed width or whatever you call that.

Comment: The real solution is "Don't have insanely long words in the first place".

Comment: i dont have control over the words the users type unfortuanately.

Comment: You should have control over the words that the system accepts though.

Comment: It's common to use a regex to detect too-long words (by number of characters) and insert spaces to break them up on the server side, at the point where the text is included in the page. This can be trickier if your text may have markup (such as links to long URLs), though.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512053/how-to-force-breaking-of-non-breakable-strings/1514590#1514590

Comment: But there can be long URLs too... perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I use the combination

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
```

to deal with this.  The `word-wrap` setting will allow the word to be wrapped despite its length in browsers which support that property, while the `overflow` setting will cause it to be cut off at the end of the available space in browsers which don't recognize `word-wrap`.  That's about as graceful of degradation as you're likely to get without going to javascript.

Comment: +1 @Dave. Thanks, this helped me today with a wrapping problem in a fieldset. Thank you!

Comment: This link also helped: http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/02/firefox-ie-word-wrap-word-break-tables.html

Comment: Seems to work on block-level elements (div) in IE but not inline elements (span). Tested in IE9 and IE11.

Answer (score 7):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break0

`word-break: break-all;`

...does not do the same as word-wrap (which is now renamed to `overflow-wrap`) because even small words may be broken when they are at the end of the line. But it works.

In some rare cases `hyphen: auto;` may bring you better results, but only if your long word is included in a dictionary the browser uses.

Comment: This works for me in Chrome 25, Firefox 19, Safari 6, Internet Explorer 9 (in Windows 7 on Parallels on a Mac; simulating IE8 and IE7 works too), stock browser and Chrome on Android 4.1, and Safari on iOS 6.1.2. But apparently [it does not work in Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-break). See also [this JS Bin example](http://jsbin.com/epejel/8/).

Answer (score 2):

In extension to the answer of Duroth, you can use the following php code to insert the shy-hyphens

```
$longest_length = 15;

$string_with_long_word = 'short lonngerrrrr lonnnnnnnggeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeessssssssssssssssstttttttttttttt and another looooooooooooonnnnnnnnngwwooooooooororoooorrrrrd';
$string = preg_replace_callback("/[a-z0-9]{{$longest_length},}/", 'putShyHyphen', $string_with_long_word);

function putShyHyphen($matches) {
 $string = $matches[0];
 $newstring = '';
 for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
  $newstring .= $string[$i] . '&shy;';
 }

 return $newstring;
}
echo $string_with_long_word . '<hr />';
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

simple css. Try this:
Put your text in `< pre>...< /pre>`

css rule

```
pre {
   overflow-x: auto; /* Use horizontal scroller if needed; for Firefox 2, not needed in Firefox 3 */
   white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
   white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
   /* width: 99%; */
   word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unless you're happy with supporting only specific browsers (IE7/Win, Safari, Firefox 3.5), there's no pure CSS solution to your problem.

**word-wrap: break-word;** works, but only in IE.

If you're able to alter the text, either server-side (PHP, ASP) or possibly client-side (Javascript), you could write a small function that inserts 'shy hyphens' (**&shy;**) into your text. That way, text can be broken up at every instance of the hyphen, and shy hyphens will not be displayed if the word is not broken up.

Edit, an example:

```
bla&shy;bla&shy;bla&shy;bla&shy;bla&shy;bla&shy;bla&shy;bla&shy;bla&shy; (etc)
```

will display as follows in your browser:

```
blablabla-
blablabla-
blabla
```

Comment: This is true, however, CSS3.0 has these properties defined (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap) so when (if!?) all browsers finally (and fully) support CSS3, we're good to go!  :)

Comment: I hope to live and see that day, CraigTP ;) Browsers tend to be terribly slow in adopting new standards...

Comment: so the file size is kind of doubled too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to resort to JavaScript and use a function like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
function wrap() {
    var data = document.getElementsByTagName('yourtaghere'); 
    var  desiredLength = 40 ;
    var delimiter = "<br />";
    for( var i=0; i < data.length; ++i ) {
        cellLength=data[i].innerHTML.length
        if( desiredLength < cellLength ) {
            var counter=0;
            var output="";
            while( counter < cellLength ) {
                output += data[i].innerHTML.substr(counter,desiredLength) + delimiter;
                counter+= desiredLength;
            }
            data[i].innerHTML=output;
        }
    }
}
window.onload=wrap;
</script>
```

Or you could use the [hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/)

Answer (score 1):

A new answer, since you've changed your question:

This is a very simplistic PHP solution:

```
<?php
$string = "AnExtremelyLongStringWithoutWhitespacesOrBreakpointsOfAnyKindThatWillCompletelyAndUtterlyRuinYourWebsiteDesign";
for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
  $newString .= $string[$i] . '&shy;';
}
echo $newString;
```

The same can be achieved in any language ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

As `word-wrap: break-word` does not work well when the width is not fixed (and even less in `<table>`), Stack Exchange adds some invisible Unicode markers, which browsers use to find possible positions for line breaks. But: those invisible markers are still there when the visitor copies the text, which might be bad. More details on Meta, in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert/.

Instead of Unicode magic, inserting `<span style="display: inline-block"></span>` every few characters seems *not* to have a bad effect when copying the resulting text. This works for me in Chrome 25, Firefox 19, Safari 6, Internet Explorer 9 (in Windows 7 on Parallels on a Mac; simulating IE8 and IE7 works too), stock browser and Chrome on Android 4.1, and Safari on iOS 6.1.2, and is [probably also supported in Opera](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html). See [this JS Bin example](http://jsbin.com/epejel/8/).

Some day, `<wbr>` will be the solution, but [not today](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html): though IE7 supported it, IE8 and IE9 don't.

Answer (score -1):

The suggested tags work to break really long words (or URLs) but you'll get mixed results from browser to browser trying to flow text in narrow divs.  For example a 200px div:

`<div style="font-size:12px;font-family:monospace;width:200px;word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;">1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890</div>`

In Chrome the numbers break, in Firefox they do not--you get two columns of numbers!  It seems Firefox doesn't consider how much space is available on the previous line of a "long" word--it doesn't break at every opportunity.  If this behavior is ever corrected, I hope Firefox also considers how this affects text justification.

The "shy" tags help Firefox but you still get "ragged" text.  I haven't done extensive tests but it appears the shy tags create unpredictable results (divs lose their style) when used in short words (less than 8 characters) in Firefox.  I personally prefer Chrome's more aggressive breaks!

Comment: If this has changed, just leave a comment and I'll delete my answer.