# How to replace text in html document without affecting the markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I write a javascript/jquery function that replaces text in the html document without affecting the markup, only the text content?

For instance if I want to replace the word "style" with "no style" here:

```
<tr>
<td style="width:300px">This TD has style</td>
<td style="width:300px">This TD has <span class="style100">style</span> too</td>
</tr>
```

I don't want the replacement to affect the markup, just the text content that is visible to the user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to look for the text nodes on your document, I use a recursive function like this:

```
function replaceText(oldText, newText, node){ 
  node = node || document.body; // base node 

  var childs = node.childNodes, i = 0;

  while(node = childs[i]){ 
    if (node.nodeType == 3){ // text node found, do the replacement
      if (node.textContent) {
        node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(oldText, newText);
      } else { // support to IE
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(oldText, newText);
      }
    } else { // not a text mode, look forward
      replaceText(oldText, newText, node); 
    } 
    i++; 
  } 
}
```

If you do it in that way, your markup and event handlers will remain intact.

**Edit:** Changed code to support IE, since the textnodes on IE don't have a [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) property, in IE you should use the [nodeValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534192(VS.85).aspx) property and it also doesn't implements the [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node) interface.

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ayibi).

Comment: Thanks a lot @CMS, you helped me resolve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512053/how-to-force-breaking-of-non-breakable-strings/

Comment: Watch out for 2011 builds of MSIE9 - they have node.textContent support, but if you try and assign a new value using `node.textContent = ...` then those builds crash the entire browser with **A problem with this website caused Internet Explorer to close**. Later builds (2012) seem OK. The workaround is to assign with `node.nodeValue = ...` inside the `if (node.textContent)` part of the loop regardless and just forget doing it with textContent.

Comment: Why won't you use `node.data` for all browsers?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`:contains`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text) selector to find elements with matching text and then replace their text.

```
$(":contains(style)").each(function() {
  for (node in this.childNodes) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text node
      node.textContent = node.textContent.replace("style", "no style");
    }
  }
});
```

Unfortunately you can't use [`text()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) for this as it strips out HTML from all descendant nodes, not just child nodes and the replacement won't work as expected.

Comment: Don't use a "for...in" to loop through an array-like-object.. a traditional for/while loop is much faster.