# Find and replace content in div's of uncertain id

Tags: javascript, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace text in html document without affecting the markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512876/how-to-replace-text-in-html-document-without-affecting-the-markup)

This should be fairly simple, I just can't seem to get it to work.
I want to take:

```
<div>Other text here XYZ more text</div>
```

and replace to get:

```
<div>Other text here ABC more text</div>
```

Where I don't know the id, class, or anything about the div and I cannot accidentally replace attributes. Just the text in-between. No Jquery.

Comment: And what have you tried? google can help you.

Comment: Apparently I just don't have a knack at getting my search terms right. :/ That solves my problems. Thanks @JosephSilber