# How can I allow text to wrap inside a word if necessary?

Tags: html, css, word-break

I am looking for the best solution to allow text to wrap in the middle of a word if necessary. By best, I mean most browser-compatible, and will favor word breaks before it breaks inside a word.

It would also help if the markup looked nicer than mine (see my answer).

**Edit:**

Note this is specifically for user-generated content.

**Edit 2:**

About 25% of Firefox users on the site in question are still using v3.0 or below, so it is critical to support them. This is based on the last month worth of data (about 121,000 visits).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no definitive answer (depends on your needs, e.g., do you want hyphens, what browsers must you support?), I did some research via [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html) to find out what the options are:

If you do not need hyphens, you will get best compatibility using `<wbr>`. If you require hyphens, then using `&shy;` is your best bet, but note that this will not work (wrap at char) in Firefox 2.0 Mac/Windows, or Safari 3.0.

And, note that if you choose to not handle long words at all by using overflow, scroll or allowing wrap at a character, both IE6 and IE7 will respond by expanding the container width (at least with the `DIV` I used), so beware.

**Results:**

```
Browser                     Method                   Wraps at char    Adds Hyphens    Overflows horizontally    Container expands horizontally
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Firefox 3.0 - Windows XP    None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 3.0 - Windows XP    <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 3.0 - Windows XP    &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
Firefox 3.0 - Windows XP    word-wrap: break-word    No               No              Yes                       No
IE7 - Windows XP            None                     No               No              No                        Yes
IE7 - Windows XP            <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
IE7 - Windows XP            &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
IE7 - Windows XP            word-wrap: break-word    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 3.0 - OS X          None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 3.0 - OS X          <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 3.0 - OS X          &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
Firefox 3.0 - OS X          word-wrap: break-word    No               No              Yes                       No
Safari 3.0 - OS X           None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Safari 3.0 - OS X           <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Safari 3.0 - OS X           &shy; or &#173;          No               No              No                        No
Safari 3.0 - OS X           word-wrap: break-word    Yes              No              No                        No
Chrome 3.0 - Windows XP     None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Chrome 3.0 - Windows XP     <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Chrome 3.0 - Windows XP     &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
Chrome 3.0 - Windows XP     word-wrap: break-word    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 2.0 - OS X          None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 2.0 - OS X          <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 2.0 - OS X          &shy; or &#173;          No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 2.0 - OS X          word-wrap: break-word    No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 2.0 - Windows XP    None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 2.0 - Windows XP    <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 2.0 - Windows XP    &shy; or &#173;          No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 2.0 - Windows XP    word-wrap: break-word    No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 3.5 - Windows XP    None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 3.5 - Windows XP    <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 3.5 - Windows XP    &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
Firefox 3.5 - Windows XP    word-wrap: break-word    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 3.5 - OS X          None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Firefox 3.5 - OS X          <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Firefox 3.5 - OS X          &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
Firefox 3.5 - OS X          word-wrap: break-word    Yes              No              No                        No
IE6 - Windows XP            None                     No               No              No                        Yes
IE6 - Windows XP            <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
IE6 - Windows XP            &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
IE6 - Windows XP            word-wrap: break-word    Yes              No              No                        No
IE8 - Windows XP            None                     No               No              Yes                       No
IE8 - Windows XP            <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
IE8 - Windows XP            &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
IE8 - Windows XP            word-wrap: break-word    Yes              No              No                        No
Safari 4.0 - OS X           None                     No               No              Yes                       No
Safari 4.0 - OS X           <wbr>                    Yes              No              No                        No
Safari 4.0 - OS X           &shy; or &#173;          Yes              Yes             No                        No
Safari 4.0 - OS X           word-wrap: break-word    Yes              No              No                        No
```

**Sample HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                width: 4em;
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-bottom: 6em;
                padding: .25em;
            }
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        This is text easily contained by the DIV:
        <div>proper width</div>

        A long word with no character breaking:
        <div>
            AReallyLongWordThatNeedsToBeBroken AndAnotherWord
        </div>

        <i>&lt;wbr&gt;</i> tag:
        <div>
            A<wbr>R<wbr>e<wbr>a<wbr>l<wbr>l<wbr>y<wbr>L<wbr>o<wbr>n<wbr>g<wbr>W<wbr>o<wbr>r<wbr>d<wbr>T<wbr>h<wbr>a<wbr>t<wbr>N<wbr>e<wbr>e<wbr>d<wbr>s<wbr>T<wbr>o<wbr>B<wbr>e<wbr>B<wbr>r<wbr>o<wbr>k<wbr>e<wbr>n A<wbr>n<wbr>d<wbr>A<wbr>n<wbr>o<wbr>t<wbr>h<wbr>e<wbr>r<wbr>W<wbr>o<wbr>r<wbr>d
        </div>

        <i>&amp;shy;</i> character:
        <div>
            A&shy;R&shy;e&shy;a&shy;l&shy;l&shy;y&shy;L&shy;o&shy;n&shy;g&shy;W&shy;o&shy;r&shy;d&shy;T&shy;h&shy;a&shy;t&shy;N&shy;e&shy;e&shy;d&shy;s&shy;T&shy;o&shy;B&shy;e&shy;B&shy;r&shy;o&shy;k&shy;e&shy;n A&shy;n&shy;d&shy;A&shy;n&shy;o&shy;t&shy;h&shy;e&shy;r&shy;W&shy;o&shy;r&shy;d
        </div>

        <i>overflow: scroll</i> CSS attribute:
        <div style="overflow: scroll">
            AReallyLongWordThatNeedsToBeBroken AndAnotherWord
        </div>

        <i>word-wrap: break-word</i> CSS attribute:
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word">
            AReallyLongWordThatNeedsToBeBroken AndAnotherWord
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You said "If you do not need hyphens, you will get best compatibility using <wbr>." Please define "compatibility". Compatibility with what? Are you only after *visual* "compatibility"? The <wbr> is word separator. Thus it splits characters into separate words. It is in fact very similar to the Zero Width Space Character. A screenreader user will hear "pres<wbr>ident" as two words.  The &shy; in contrast, does not split a word. Neither does CSS word-wrap. <wbr> is also porly supported. Opera does not support it. IE8 and IE9 do not either. And for those who support implementation varies.

Comment: Compatibility was a very poor word choice. Substitute "visual effect", perhaps.

Comment: `<wbr>` is genius!

Answer (score 25):

The css property `word-wrap: break-word` will force long words to wrap to the next line if they are too long for their container.  This is supported by IE (going way back), Firefox and Safari.

Edit: Looks like you may be able to achieve this in older versions of Firefox as well using `white-space: -moz-pre-wrap` and `white-space: pre-wrap`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) for more info. I have not tested this with older versions of Firefox though.

Comment: In FF is is not as long supported as in MSIE and Safari (it is originally a MSIE proprietary property). FF only supports it since 3.5 which is not a year old yet. Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap

Comment: I expect that Firefox users are pretty good about upgrading. :-) The data seem to suggest it: http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2

Comment: @T.J. - see my edit to the OP. My data is similar to that article, and I can't allow the site to break for 5% of the users.

Comment: @T.J. that's very true :) The browser by default upgrades itself automagically. Still, it's something to keep in mind. It may depend on target group of the website in question.

Comment: @BalusC: Absolutely, I thought it was a very useful thing you pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

My answer from another instance of this question, found at [Wrapping long text in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470810/wrapping-long-text-in-css/1471103#1471103) :

I use the combination

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
```

to deal with this.  The `word-wrap` setting will allow the word to be wrapped despite its length in browsers which support that property, while the `overflow` setting will cause it to be cut off at the end of the available space in browsers which don't recognize `word-wrap`.  That's about as graceful of degradation as you're likely to get without going to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

[**Edit**: OP updated his question to say this is specifically for user-generated content; the below won't (easily) work for that (you'd have to have your own hyphenation dictionary). Leaving it here, though, in case someone finds this question and needs an HTML option for doing this.]

You can use a soft hyphen (aka optional hyphen; `&shy;` or `&#173;`). It was defined way back in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.3). I've never used it, but I just tried and it works in: IE6, IE7, Chrome 4, FF 3.6, and Safari 4 for Windows at least.

One *could* argue that the user-agent (browser) should handle this automatically (using a hyphenation dictionary for the language the document is in). <s>In practice, I don't know of a single web browser that does it automatically.</s> Apparently, modern browsers do if you tell them they can; see wsanville's answer for a CSS option.

Comment: This won't work for user-generated content, unless you add the soft hyphen dynamically, similar to my response.

Comment: @OrbMan: Absolutely, I'd definitely use `break-word` whenever possible.

Comment: If soft hyphen works on Safari (and at least FF 3.0+), I am liking this answer the best, so far (for compatiblity reasons only). Do you have any information on Safari compatibility?

Comment: @OrbMan: It happens I have that installed. :-) Yes, Safari 4 for Windows (no great surprise, both that and Chrome are WebKit-based). Also Opera 10 and IE6.

Comment: +1 for useful info; I ended up answering my own question due to need for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar answer here: 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

A more robust browser support

**CSS only**

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;

     /* Be VERY careful with this, breaks normal words wh_erever */
     word-break: break-all;

     /* Non standard for webkit */
     word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
```

If your **text is PHP generated** you have a **PHP function**:

[wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
<?php
  $text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
  $newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

  echo $newtext;
?>
```

Also, you can try **PHP function explode** if you have and know the delimiter.
Display after with for loop (explode returns an array).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the `word-wrap: break-word` CSS property.

The following example works in Google Chrome 4.0, Firefox 3.5.7, Safari 4.0.4, and IE 8:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 50px;">
        Loremipsumdolorsitametconsectetueradipiscingelitselaoreetdoloremagnaaliq
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately as noted by [BalusC in a comment to one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257657/how-can-i-allow-text-to-wrap-inside-a-word-if-necessary/2257685#2257685), the above [will not work in versions of Firefox older than 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap). Since the population of users using old Firefox versions [seems to be below ~6%](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2), as [noted by T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257657/how-can-i-allow-text-to-wrap-inside-a-word-if-necessary/2257685#2257685), you may want to fallback to an `overflow: scroll` for browsers that do not support `word-wrap`. It may not look very nice, but if you are not expecting many words to be longer than the allocated space, the probability that one of the users will see the scroll bar would be very low, and it will get even lower as time passes and users upgrade their browsers. At least you would be failing gracefully in those situations.

Comment: I need support for Firefox below v3.5

Comment: Updated answer with my thoughts on this :)

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used something like this, (which did not work on Safari at the time, IIRC, but that was several years ago):

`A<wbr>V<wbr>e<wbr>r<wbr>y<wbr>L<wbr>o<wbr>n<wbr>g<wbr>W<wbr>o<wbr>r<wbr>d A<wbr>n<wbr>d<wbr>A<wbr>n<wbr>o<wbr>t<wbr>h<wbr>e<wbr>r<wbr>W<wbr>o<wbr>r<wbr>d`

(I would generate this dynamically so that the person doing layout would not have to look at such an atrocity.)

Answer (score 0):

Enter keyboard line break at the point at which you want it to break.

eg.

Thisisaverylongword

would become

Thisisavery
longword

Comment: He he. This advice is just as good as using <wbr>. <wbr> is OK if you *do* want to separate a line into words without making it visual. But, in fact, the Zero Width Space has better support: &#x200B; Though as always ... everything depends.

Comment: Thanks @Komputist , I was having some table CSS issues and suddenly realised IE9 wasn't breaking where it should be - but the &#x200B; works on both IE9 and chrome - cheers