# Simple CSS! When a lot of text is in my div, it just continues in one straight line instead of going to next line? Width is set

Tags: css, html, paragraph

I have a set width and the height is set to auto. 
Each row is a `div`, inside is a `div` for each column. and there is a `<p>` tag inside the column divs where text should be.
The CSS involved is very basic, just some padding and set width/heights...
and float left.

Something I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please post at least the relevant parts of the css and perhaps the html too?

Comment: Why divs? This looks like tabular data to me. That's what tables are for.

Comment: I was asked to do it with divs. I could post it but its not really different from what I just wrote up theree..

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257657/how-can-i-allow-text-to-wrap-inside-a-word-if-necessary/2257685#2257685

Comment: 'Something I'm missing?' *yes,* most of the question. What's your CSS what's your **actual** (x)html mark-up?

Comment: Whoever told you to do it with divs ought to be drawn and quartered.

Comment: The browser will have problems displaying text with no white space. Normally, you can get text to wrap if it has white space. Probably the best you can do is to get scroll bars to appear or appropriately size the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually expected behavior for your code. You have a single "word" in your "cell", with no spaces in it. So browser doesn't know where to wrap and automatically extends the box. You should add `word-wrap: break-word` CSS rule to `.orderHistoryTable` selector (or to `orderHistoryTable div.row1` if you want this behavior only on this cell)

http://jsfiddle.net/d2Amf/

Comment: word-wrap: break-word; is great but does not work in older versions of IE. If you want your site to be cross-browser compatible it's important to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the CSS `overflow` property?

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html

Answer (score 0):

I live and breath by the Clearfix method. It will solve many of your layout problems w/ divs. It might solve this issue you're having, or might not, but overall it's great to use when doing div heavy layouts. I use Jeff Starr's method from Perishable Press: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/