# soft hyphen character does not work in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, html

Soft hyphen (`&shy;`) does not work in IE8.
I am using it to break a long words in div to multiple lines.
It works in IE7, IE9 and other browsers, any remedy for that?

try jsFiddle.net example:

http://jsfiddle.net/puv75/

Comment: more details about solution here-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257657/how-can-i-allow-text-to-wrap-inside-a-word-if-necessary

Comment: Hi Jonathan I am simulating IE8 on IE9 with Win7, it does not work.

Comment: thanks rt2800, I think it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, it seems that this is a bug in the way IE 9 simulates IE 8, rather than in real IE 8. See http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/issues/detail?id=153