# my text is exceeding my div I use jquery and key up object to retrive data in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

my text is exceeding my div I use keyup to retrieve data from textarea to div. but my text is exceeding my div! In this image my text is exceeding from my div but the exceeding text must be in next line. link is given bellow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vvnK.png

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470810/wrapping-long-text-in-css and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div

Answer (score -1):

Your `jjjj[...]kkkk[...]LLL` is **only one word** and this is why your text exceed your div.

use css property `overflow: hidden;` and dont use words with 9898374297 characters.

Comment: when I use separate words it gives the same result